# How can I apply a prefix to dictionary access?

Tags: python

I'm imitating the behavior of the `ConfigParser` module to write a highly specialized parser that exploits some well-defined structure in the configuration files for a particular application I work with.  Several sections of the config file contain hundreds of variable and routine mappings prefixed with either `Variable_` or `Routine_`, like this:

```
[Map.PRD]
Variable_FOO=LOC1
Variable_BAR=LOC2
Routine_FOO=LOC3
Routine_BAR=LOC4
...

[Map.SHD]
Variable_FOO=LOC1
Variable_BAR=LOC2
Routine_FOO=LOC3
Routine_BAR=LOC4
...
```

I'd like to maintain the basic structure of `ConfigParser` where each section is stored as a single dictionary, so users would still have access to the classic syntax:

```
config.content['Mappings']['Variable_FOO'] = 'LOC1'
```

but also be able to use a simplified API that drills down to this section:

```
config.vmapping('PRD')['FOO'] = 'LOC1'
config.vmapping('PRD')['BAR'] = 'LOC2'
config.rmapping('PRD')['FOO'] = 'LOC3'
config.rmapping('PRD')['BAR'] = 'LOC4'
```

Currently I'm implementing this by storing the section in a special subclass of `dict` to which I've added a `prefix` attribute.  The `variable` and `routine` properties of the parser set the `prefix` attribute of the `dict`-like object to `'Variable_'` or `'Routine_'` and then modified `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` attributes of the `dict` handle gluing the prefix together with the key to access the appropriate item.  It's working, but involves a lot of boilerplate to implement all the associated niceties like supporting iteration.

I suppose my ideal solution would be do dispense with the subclassed `dict` and have have the `variable` and `routine` properties somehow present a "view" of the plain `dict` object underneath without the prefixes.

### Update

Here's the solution I implemented, largely based on @abarnet's answer:

```
class MappingDict(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix, d):
        self.prefix, self.d = prefix, d
    def prefixify(self, name):
        return '{}_{}'.format(self.prefix, name)
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        name = self.prefixify(name)
        return self.d.__getitem__(name)
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        name = self.prefixify(name)
        return self.d.__setitem__(name, value)
    def __delitem__(self, name):
        name = self.prefixify(name)
        return self.d.__delitem__(name)
    def __iter__(self):
        return (key.partition('_')[-1] for key in self.d
                if key.startswith(self.prefix))
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MappingDict({})'.format(dict.__repr__(self))

class MyParser(object):
    SECTCRE = re.compile(r'\[(?P<header>[^]]+)\]')
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.content = {}
        lines = [x.strip() for x in open(filename).read().splitlines() 
                 if x.strip()]
        for line in lines:
            match = re.match(self.SECTCRE, line)
            if match:
                section = match.group('header')
                self.content[section] = {}
            else:
                key, sep, value = line.partition('=')
                self.content[section][key] = value
    def write(self, filename):
        fp = open(filename, 'w')
        for section in sorted(self.content, key=sectionsort):
            fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
            for key in sorted(self.content[section], key=cpfsort):
                value = str(self.content[section][key])
                fp.write("%s\n" % '='.join([key,value]))
            fp.write("\n")
        fp.close()
    def vmapping(self, nsp):
        section = 'Map.{}'.format(nsp)
        return MappingDict('Variable', self.content[section])
    def rmapping(self, nsp):
        section = 'Map.{}'.format(nsp)
        return MappingDict('Routine', self.content[section])
```

It's used like this:

```
config = MyParser('myfile.cfg')
vmap = config.vmapping('PRD')
vmap['FOO'] = 'LOC5'
vmap['BAR'] = 'LOC6'
config.write('newfile.cfg')
```

The resulting `newfile.cfg` reflects the `LOC5` and `LOC6` changes.

Comment: Well, you can't actually have an attribute named `global`, because that's a keyword…

Comment: @abarnert I changed `global` to `variable` to simplify the discussion.

Comment: Some clarification, should iterating over the config dict also iterate through the variable/routing 'sub-dicts' ? Also, would `config['variable']['FOO'] be out of the question?

Comment: I don't think descriptors are going to help here. `variable` and `routine` have to return some kind of object that you construct, and there's no good reason not to construct those objects at initialization.

Comment: Can't `config.variable` and `config.routine` just be separate `dict`s in each instance?

Comment: @martineau: That's the first suggestion in my answer. You need to create separate de-prefixified `dict` objects right after load, and re-prefix and merge right before save, but that isn't really complicated.

Comment: @abarnert @martineau Part of my reason for wanting a single dict is so people can have it both ways.  If you're used to the raw configuration file, you would be able to call `config[section]['Routine_FOO'] = 'LOC1'`, but the nice `config.routine['FOO'] = 'LOC1'` syntax would be available as a shortcut.

Comment: @JeffKlukas: I think my answer shows you how to do that. But remember that in Python, TOOWTDI is one of the guiding principles, and that should often be just as true of your APIs as of the core language.

Comment: @JeffKlukas: I think @abarnet is right, users can always make their own, even shorter, shortcuts with something like `routine = config['Routine']` then `routine['FOO'] = 'LOC1'`, etc.

Comment: @martineau Fantastic suggestion!  Being able to mangle the `dict` through a reference separate from the `Config` instance will cut out even more boilerplate code for end users.

Comment: @JeffKlukas: I'd like how you implemented things, perhaps you could update your question and show us. Thanks.

Comment: @martineau: I've updated the question with my implemented solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want inheritance here. You end up with two separate `dict` objects which you have to create on load and then paste back together on save…

If that's acceptable, you don't even need to bother with the prefixing during normal operations; just do the prefixing while saving, like this:

```
class Config(object):
    def save(self):
        merged = {'variable_{}'.format(key): value for key, value 
                  in self.variable_dict.items()}
        merged.update({'routine_{}'.format(key): value for key, value 
                       in self.routine_dict.items()}
        # now save merged
```

If you want that `merged` object to be visible at all times, but don't expect to be called on that very often, make it a `@property`.

If you want to access the `merged` dictionary regularly, at the same time you're accessing the two sub-dictionaries, then yes, you want a view:

> I suppose my ideal solution would be do dispense with the subclassed dict and have have the global and routine properties somehow present a "view" of the plain dict object underneath without the prefixes.

This is going to be very hard to do with inheritance. Certainly not with inheritance from `dict`; inheritance from `builtins.dict_items` might work if you're using Python 3, but it still seems like a stretch.

But with delegation, it's easy. Each sub-dictionary just holds a reference to the parent `dict`:

```
class PrefixedDict(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix, d):
        self.prefix, self.d = prefix, d
    def prefixify(self, key):
        return '{}_{}'.format(self.prefix, key)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.d.__getitem__(self.prefixify(key))
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return self.d.__setitem__(self.prefixify(key), value)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return self.d.__delitem__(self.prefixify(key))
    def __iter__(self):
        return (key[len(self.prefix):] for key in self.d 
                if key.startswith(self.prefix)])
```

You don't get any of the `dict` methods for free that way—but that's a good thing, because they were mostly incorrect anyway, right? Explicitly delegate the ones you want. (If you do have some you want to pass through as-is, use `__getattr__` for that.)

Besides being conceptually simpler and harder to screw up through accidentally forgetting to override something, this also means that `PrefixDict` can work with any type of mapping, not just a `dict`.

---

So, no matter which way you go, where and how do these objects get created?

The easy answer is that they're attributes that you create when you construct a `Config`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.d = {}
    self.variable = PrefixedDict('Variable', self.d)
    self.routine = PrefixedDict('Routine', self.d)
```

If this needs to be dynamic (e.g., there can be an arbitrary set of prefixes), create them at load time:

```
def load(self):
    # load up self.d
    prefixes = set(key.split('_')[0] for key in self.d)
    for prefix in prefixes:
        setattr(self, prefix, PrefixedDict(prefix, self.d)
```

If you want to be able to create them on the fly (so `config.newprefix['foo'] = 3` adds `'Newprefix_foo'`), you can do this instead:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return PrefixedDict(name.title(), self.d)
```

But once you're using dynamic attributes, you really have to question whether it isn't cleaner to use dictionary (item) syntax instead, like `config['newprefix']['foo']`. For one thing, that would actually let you call one of the sub-dictionaries `'global'`, as in your original question…

Or you can first build the dictionary syntax, use what's usually referred to as an `attrdict` (search ActiveState recipes and PyPI for 3000 implementations…), which lets you automatically make `config.newprefix` mean `config['newprefix']`, so you can use attribute syntax when you have valid identifiers, but fall back to dictionary syntax when you don't.

Comment: In this solution, is the `PrefixedDict` actually looking back at the `Config` instance's `d` attribute?  It looks like it would just be copying in the contents of d at initialization time.  If the `PrefixedDict` could actually reach back and modify the contents of the `Config` instance's main dictionary, this could be a great solution.

Comment: It _is_ reaching back. When you do `self.d = d`, that's just making another reference to the same `dict` object. So, as long as Config just mutates its `self.d` in-place (instead of rebinding it to a whole new `dict`), they're pointing at the same thing. Just like you need to do things like `d.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy(d)` to _avoid_ sharing when you don't want it, you just need to avoid calling those functions to benefit from sharing when you _do_ want it.

Comment: @JeffKlukas: If you're not quite getting that, look at it this way: You can always hold a reference to the parent `Config` object itself, and do `self.config.d`, right? (Don't do that, because that means a circular reference, which causes problems for the GC, but other than that, it works fine.) It's the same thing. A `dict` is an Python object, just like a `Config`. (I don't mean "object" in the sense of "instance of a subclass of `object`"—that's true in Ruby, Smalltalk, etc., but not Python. I mean "object" in the sense of "a thing that you can reference".)

Comment: I just tested out a simplified version of this, and darned if it doesn't reference the `Config` objects `d` attribute just like you said.  I'm familiar with the need for `deepcopy` and friends, but somehow assumed the reference behavior wouldn't survive getting passed as an argument.

Comment: I was going to suggest a simple alternative which I see someone has already mentioned in a [comment](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict/#c3) to one of ActiveState's [`attrdict`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict/) recipes.

Comment: @martineau: Yeah, a JS-object-style default-attrdict (you can find complete, tested implementations of such on PyPI) isn't quite the same thing the OP asked for, but it may be close enough to make him happy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options for how to proceed.

The simplest might be to use nested dictionaries, so `Variable_FOO` becomes `config["variable"]["FOO"]`. You might want to  use a `defaultdict(dict)` for the outer dictionary so you don't need to worry about initializing the inner ones when you add the first value to them.

Another option would be to use tuple keys in a single dictionary. That is, `Variable_FOO` would become `config[("variable", "FOO")]`. This is easy to do with code, since you can simply assign to `config[tuple(some_string.split("_"))]`. Though, I suppose you could also just use the unsplit string as your key in this case.

A final approach allows you to use the syntax you want (where `Variable_FOO` is accessed as `config.Variable["FOO"]`), by using `__getattr__` and a `defaultdict` behind the scenes:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attrdicts = defaultdict(dict)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._attrdicts[name]
```

You could extend this with behavior for `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` but it's probably not necessary. The only serious limitation to this approach (given the original version of the question), is that the attributes names (like `Variable`) must be legal Python identifiers. You can't use strings with leading numbers, Python keywords (like `global`) or strings containing whitespace characters.

A downside to this approach is that it's a bit more difficult to use programatically (by, for instance, your config-file parser). To read a value of `Variable_FOO` and save it to `config.Variable["FOO"]` you'll probably need to use the global `getattr` function, like this:

```
 name, value = line.split("=")
 prefix, suffix = name.split("_")
 getattr(config, prefix)[suffix] = value
```